# nodejs websocket and http basic auth

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, basic-authentication

I'd like to implement http basic auth authentication into my nodejs websocket app. Here's my piece of code:

```
var http = require('http');
var auth = require('http-auth');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

//....

basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "websocket auth",
    file: __dirname + "/users.htpasswd"
});

var server = http.createServer(basic);
app.listen = function() {
    return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};

// WEBSOCKET
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

wss.on('request', function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept();

    connection.sendUTF('Server: message ws auth');
});
```

For standard http access authentication it works fine, but I can't get it working on websocket, when I connect through websocket I immediately get response. Is it even possible to authenticate via http on websocket?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

Websockets aren't HTTP so they don't do things like HTTP AUTH, send cookies, etc.

For our websocket connections we pass in the cookie as a parameter on the request URL.  We are using socket.io, however, which has a provision for setting an authentication function sort of similar to an HTTP server's middleware.

You should be able to do something similar with the [`#accept`](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/wiki/Documentation#acceptacceptedprotocol-allowedorigin) method from Websocket-node. Examine the data coming in and if it's not authorized, reject the connection.

Comment: Thanks, but according to RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-53 it looks like I should be able to do http authentication before http server does upgrade to websocket protocol.

Comment: Are you sure you're negotiating an upgrade via HTTP first?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, therefore  httpServer is also passed to WebSocketServer object.